# Access controller data from route provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app with a router and a bunch of controllers, organized like

```
articleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/articles', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/articles/index.html'
      }).
      when('/articles/:articleId', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/articles/article.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/articles'
      });
  }]);
```

The controllers are given in the templates, e.g.,

```
<div ng-controller="ArticleCtrl">
  <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

Now, I would like to set `<head>` data like page title, `meta` data etc. depending on the route and the contents of the page. The data is obviously in the controllers, so that's where I'm setting the `<head>` data now.

Unfortunately, this is becoming quite a mess: A controller here, a controller there, perhaps active in the same view, this one sets the page title, that one sets the page title... A debugging labyrinth.

Ideally, I would like to set meta data in one place only, and the `$routeProvider` above seems ideal to me. Unfortunately, though, we dont't have access to the data of the controllers there. Or do we?

Is it possible to access controller data from the `$routeProvider`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are tackling the problem the wrong way. If this data is needed *above* the scope of the controller, it should be *resolved* before the instantiation of the controller. You would then inject this data in the controller the same way you inject any component.

See in particular the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for the `resolve` property on `$routeProvider`.

Here is an example:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/phone/:phoneId', {
         controller: 'PhoneDetailController',
         templateUrl: 'phone.detail.html',
         resolve: {
             routeMetadata: function () {
                 return {
                     title: 'Phone product page',
                     keywords: ['phone', 'mobile', 'cellular']
                 }
             }
         }
    });
```

In the controller you just have to inject `routeMetadata`:

```
app.controller('PhoneDetailController', function (..., routeMetadata, ...) {
    // ...
}
```

Besides the `resolve` property which is useful in particular if you need to fetch data from an api, you could also use a *trick*: define the data at the top level of the route definition:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/phone/:phoneId', {
         controller: 'PhoneDetailController',
         templateUrl: 'phone.detail.html',
         routeMetadata: {
             title: 'Phone product page',
             keywords: ['phone', 'mobile', 'cellular']
         }
    });
```

This data is then accessible in `$route.current`. Although I write about this, I would rather go with the `resolve` property. The latter is more a workaround, as the difference between properties defined by the module `ngRoute` and *custom* properties is not obvious.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some sample code, might be useful for someone.

Comment: Can I also access the `resolve`d data from `$route.current`?

Comment: Yes, the `resolve` property could be accessed from `$route.current`, although it is not a usual way to access it. Btw, seems that the `current` property is defined on `$route` only if you setted up a listener on an event like `routeChangeStart`.

Comment: That's how we plan to use it. Basically there's a service that listens for `routeChangeStart`, fetches the properties from `$route.current`, and uses it to set the page meta data. I'll give it a spin.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in the title tag like

```
<title>{{ PageSettings.title() }}</title>
```

Then add a service for it

```
myModule.factory('PageSettings', function() {
   var title = 'default';
   return {
     title: function() { return title; },
     setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
   };
});
```

In your route config, add title

```
articleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/articles', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/articles/index.html',
        title: 'Articles'
      }).
      when('/articles/:articleId', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/articles/article.html',
        title: 'Article'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/articles'
      });
  }]);
```

Then you can write your controller like this

```
function MainCtrl($scope,  $route, PageSettings) {
  PageSettings.setTitle($route.current.title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Meeh for this idea. I don't see how that solves the problem though. I'll still have all `setTitles` scattered across the controllers, whereas I'd rather call `setTitle` from the `$routeProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use more information for page like

- Title
- Meta Data
- Keywords
- Description
- and many more

Then I will suggest to use [angularjs-viewhead](https://github.com/apparentlymart/angularjs-viewhead)

If only one or two info then you can set them in routing and at the time of changing the route you can set that.

See how I achieved it by using `ui-router`

```
.state('permission', {
    title: 'Permission',
    url: '/permission',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/permission.html',
    controller: 'permissionCtrl',
    data: {
        Roles: [Constants.Roles.admin, Constants.Roles.analyst]
    }
})
.state('products', {
    title: 'products Page',
    url: '/products',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/products.html'
});
```

An on changing the route

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state',  function ($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,  next) {

    // Page Title
    $rootScope.title = next.title;
});
```

}]);

In Html

```
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
```

Comment: How can I set it at routing? I need info from the respective controller to set, e.g., the page title. How to access controller data in the `$routeProvider`?